# What do you call the target of ‘purge’?

Tags: single-word-requests

I find the word, ‘purger’ in a popular English-Japanese dictionary (Kenkyusha's Readers English Japanese Dictionary) as a derivative from 'purge,' without definition. I took it for those who purge someone who is harmful or undesired to an organization or country, though it can mean 'pulifier'in correct sense. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

If purger means someone who purges an unacceptable person, how do you call the target of ‘purger’ other than ‘the purged’ which I can think of?

Like ‘persecutee’ as the target of ‘persecutor’, which I find in the same dictionary, can I say ‘purgee’ to this effect?

Comment: Context?  Is the "purger" vomiting or cleaning their closet?

Comment: I think you mean to ask what is that TARGET of a purger called, rather than what the antonym is. A word meaning the opposite of "purger" might be recruiter, for example. I suggest you edit your title and question accordingly.

Comment: @Jim A [relational antonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_(semantics)#Relational_antonyms) deals with opposite sides of a relationship, like teacher and student, or purger and what this question asks for.

Comment: @Jim. Thank you for advice. I revised the title and the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider the noun **purged**, but before you do, also consider the [Great Purge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Purge), which is described as

> a campaign of political repression in the Soviet Union orchestrated by
>   Joseph Stalin from 1934 to 1939.

This involved the *repression* or *prosecution* of people considered counter-revolutionaries and enemies of the people by the leadership of the Soviet Union.

So the word **repressed** may suffice, but it doesn't have the same sense as *purged*, where a purge is

> an abrupt or violent removal of a group of people from an organization or place.

You obviously also considered how the verb *persecute* works here, but even *persecute* does not carry the full meaning of being removed as *purge* does. (Otherwise **persecuted** rather than *persecutee* would be the right form of the word.)

Using the word *purged* as a noun is useful if you are describing a number of people (*The purged were sent to the Gulags*). But when describing an individual, it doesn't work. (*He was one of the purged.* or simply *He was purged.*) *Repressed* and *persecuted* would be used in a similar way.

Let's consider your own example of *persecutee* or *purgee*. While this form finds its way into common discourse, it still sounds rather tortured and/or legalistic, and in many cases, as I described above, a more natural sounding form already exists.

Answer (score 4):

Is antonym really the word you're looking for? Persecutee is not the antonym of persecutor. If you mean what your question asks, the antonym is "binger":

> [binge](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/binger) — a period or bout, usually brief, of excessive indulgence, as in eating, drinking alcoholic beverages, etc.; spree.

Comment: It is better as an answer!

Comment: I added a definition to the answer. If it isn't the correct word feel free to replace it with a more appropriate definition.

Comment: _Persecutor/persecuted_ is not the same **kind** of antonym as _hot/cold,_ but it's still [a kind of antonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_(semantics)#Relational_antonyms).